# Как получить значения семплов в audioWorklet?

Tags: javascript, c, webassembly

У меня есть буфер входящих аудио фреймов в wasm модуль.

```
 void Process(uintptr_t input_ptr, uintptr_t output_ptr,
               unsigned channel_count) {


    double* input_buffer = reinterpret_cast<double*>(input_ptr);
    double* output_buffer = reinterpret_cast<double*>(output_ptr);

    for (unsigned channel = 0; channel < channel_count; ++channel) {

      double* destination = output_buffer + channel * kernel_buffer_size_;

      if (channel < channel_count) {
        double* source = input_buffer + channel * kernel_buffer_size_;

        memcpy(destination, source, bytes_per_channel_);
      } else {
        memset(destination, 0, bytes_per_channel_);
      }
    }
  }
```

Как мне получить значения семплов которые находятся в буфере ?

Comment: А чем Вас не устраивает  *source[0],    source[1],  source[2]...* ?

Comment: О. спасибо. У меня пока плохо с представлением c кода, а мне работу помяти организовать надо..